# QPainter is drawing rectangle but not displaying the rectangle box

Tags: c++, qt

It's really a strange problem to me. Let me explain first.

I am trying to develop a `Qt` application to crop objects from an image.
There, while I am cropping by mouse right button, I am using `QPainter` to draw the rectangle by `QPainter::setPen()` function and display it.

But I observed that when the image size is so big (like let's say 3000 pixel x 4000 pixel), `QPainter` is drawing the rectangle, but it can not be visualized after some portion.

For smaller images, it shows the rectangle fine.

For example, I am trying to crop 150 pixel x 150 pixel object from 3000 pixel x 4000 pixel image.

When I start cropping, it shows the rectangle fine.
But when I starts moving mouse to draw 150 x 150 rectangle, it stops displaying let's say after 50 x 50 pixel.

When I release mouse, I am displaying the rectangle in a another `QWidget`, where I see the rectangle it displayed was 150 x 150 pixel instead of 50 x 50 (that means exactly what I cropped).

The codes written below is used to draw the rectangle.

```
QPainter paint;    
paint.begin(&scaled);
paint.setBrush(Qt::blue);
paint.setPen(Qt::blue);
paint.setOpacity(0.5); // Between 0 and 1.
paint.drawRect(rectangle);
paint.end();
```

Can anyone tell me why it is happening so?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As long as nothing says about paint event we can assume the flow is maybe incorrect. You need to use QPainter from pain event handler and call widget update() not from paint event handler for the case when the drawing must change. https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_use_QPainter

Comment: Hey Alexander. thanks for your comment and sorry for my late reply. Still I am facing this problem. I can share the link of code if it doesn't bother you.

Comment: Of course you can share more complete code for understanding the problem and you should have when posting the question.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/ashraful100/Cropping-App/blob/master/mainwindow.cpp) is the complete code. The problem regarding the `QPainter` is in `Mainwindow::slotMouseMovedWithRightClickDown(QRect rectangle)`

Comment: The code has no paint event handler and you should follow https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_use_QPainter. ALL draw actions can only be called from paintEvent handler and wherever you now do paint directly you should do thisWidget->update().